# Does a wave of depolarization towards a positive electrode always result in positive deflection on ECG?

Tags: electrocardiogram

Pretty much what the text says. For the sake of simplicity let's imagine we have this scenario here:

https://www.google.com/search?q=ecg+guyton+and+hall&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiytbWE7Y7gAhVBf7wKHfhQBzwQ2-cCegQIABAC&oq=ecg+guyton+and+hall&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-img.3...1709.2061..2424...0.0..0.357.1035.3-3......0....1.Pi1Hx7uL2JY&ei=VBtOXLK7O8H-8QX4oZ3gAw&client=tablet-android-asus-tpin&prmd=ivn#imgrc=CRPIwiuQdVOeEM

Now my question is. Say we took the same myocardial fiber in a resting(polarized) state and gave it a STIMULUS but at a location past the HALF-WAY point and at the same time let's just imagine there was a BLOCK at the same level of the stimulus so that the depolarization wave couldn't go back towards the Negative electrode only towards the Positive electrode. Would it still give a positive deflection??

Comment: Is your question answered if I remind you that measured electrical potentials (voltages) are always relative to something? That is, voltage is a difference in electrical potential between Point A and Point B?

Comment: I believe from what I understood It would be a a POSITIVE DEFLECTION but with a smaller amplitude. Is that correct?